# Difference between \DeclareTCBox and \DeclareTotalTCBox in package tcolorbox

Tags: tcolorbox

What's the difference between `\DeclareTCBox` and `\DeclareTotalTCBox` in package `tcolorbox`?

I've read the manual of package `tcolorbox` (pages 466-467), but I'm still confused with them.

Comment: I've never used them, but documentation says that `Total` box also declares the contents of the box while in `DeclareTCBox` you have to add the contents when you call the command inside the text. Why is this useful? I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference is that `\DeclareTotalTCBox` accepts a forth mandatory argument `<(tcbox) content>`, which could be a pattern making use of arguments in `<(xparse) arg specification>`. (And `\DeclareTCBox` defined command requires one more mandatory argument.)

For example, in

```tex
% syntax
% \DeclareTotalTCBox \<name> {<arg spec>} {<options>} {<box content>}
\DeclareTotalTCBox   \mybox  { O{} m }    {<options>} {<box content>}
```

you can use `#1` and `#2` in `<box content>`.

With the help of options `before upper app` and `after upper pre` from `hooks` library, `\DeclareTCBox` can more or less simulate the effect of corresponding "total" one, though you have to give an extra mandatory and possibly empty argument to the defined `\<name>`.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks, xparse, minted}

\tcbset{
  my verb/.style 2 args={
    fontupper=\ttfamily,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
    top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,
    leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0.3mm,bottomrule=0.3mm,boxsep=0.5mm,
    colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black,
    #2
  }
}

% from dexteritas's answer
\DeclareTCBox     {\myverbA}{ O{red} }       {my verb={#1}{}}
\DeclareTotalTCBox{\myverbB}{ O{red} v !O{} }{my verb={#1}{#3}}{#2}
\DeclareTotalTCBox{\myverbC}{ O{red} v !O{} }{my verb={#1}{#3}}{foo #2 bar}

% use \DeclareTCBox to simulate \DeclareTotalTCBox
\DeclareTCBox     {\myverbD}{ O{red} v !O{} }{my verb={#1}{#3}, before upper app={#2}}
\DeclareTCBox     {\myverbE}{ O{red} v !O{} }{my verb={#1}{#3}, before upper app={foo #2 bar}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tcblisting}{sidebyside}
  \Verb|\DeclareTCBox| \\
  \myverbA{\LaTeX}     \\
  
  \Verb|\DeclareTotalCBox| \\
  \myverbB{\LaTeX} \\
  \myverbC{\LaTeX} \\

  Simulate \Verb|\DeclareTotalCBox| \\
  \myverbD{\LaTeX}{} \\
  \myverbE{\LaTeX}{} \\
\end{tcblisting}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

#### Definition

The definitions from the manual of [`tcolorbox`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) of these two commands are:

```
\DeclareTCBox[⟨init options⟩]{\⟨name⟩}{⟨specification⟩}{⟨options⟩}
\DeclareTotalTCBox[⟨init options⟩]{\⟨name⟩}{⟨specification⟩}{⟨options⟩}{⟨content⟩}
```

So `\DeclareTotalTCBox` allows you to define how the content should be inputted and used, while `\DeclareTCBox` just inserts the last `{...}` as content.

#### Differences

`\DeclareTotalTCBox` can do the same as `DeclareTCBox` (using `m` as last parameter in the specification and using that parameter as contents):

```
\DeclareTotalTCBox[⟨init options⟩]{\⟨name⟩}{⟨specification⟩ m}{⟨options⟩}{#⟨last parameter⟩}
```

But it can also do more:

- In the example of `\DeclareTotalTCBox` in the manual, the content should be verbatim, which is done by specification `v` (see `\myverbB` in MWE below), which is not possible with `\DeclareTCBox` (see `\myverbA`).
- Furthermore it is possible to add some text or commands to the content (see `\myverbC`).

#### Example

Here is a MWE (using some code of the manual example):

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{xparse}

\begin{document}

\DeclareTCBox{\myverbA}{ O{red} }
{ fontupper=\ttfamily,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,
leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0.3mm,bottomrule=0.3mm,boxsep=0.5mm,
colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black}

Here is an example: \myverbA{\LaTeX}.

\bigskip

\DeclareTotalTCBox{\myverbB}{ O{red} v !O{} }
{ fontupper=\ttfamily,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,
leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0.3mm,bottomrule=0.3mm,boxsep=0.5mm,
colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black,#3}{#2}

Here is an example: \myverbB{\LaTeX}.

\bigskip

\DeclareTotalTCBox{\myverbC}{ O{red} v !O{} }
{ fontupper=\ttfamily,nobeforeafter,tcbox raise base,arc=0pt,outer arc=0pt,
top=0pt,bottom=0pt,left=0mm,right=0mm,
leftrule=0pt,rightrule=0pt,toprule=0.3mm,bottomrule=0.3mm,boxsep=0.5mm,
colback=#1!10!white,colframe=#1!50!black,#3}{foo #2 bar}

Here is an example: \myverbC{\LaTeX}.

\end{document}
```

#### Result

[image]

#### Notes

- For more information on the specification see package `xparse` and [The DeclareTotalTCBox command (tcolorbox package)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/269333/123129)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, That's great!